# limit the instance of silverlight application to one

Tags: silverlight, silverlight-4.0

How to make sure that only one instance of a silver light web out of browser application is running?

How to make sure that only one instance of a silverlight web application inside the web browser is running?

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the part of the Silverlight Docs:  [Implement Communication Between Local Silverlight-Based Applications](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd833075%28v=VS.95%29.aspx)

You can use the `LocalMessageSender` and `LocalMessageReceiver`.  Create a sender and send a message, if you get a response inform the user by loading an alternate root visual.  If you don't get a response set up a receiver so that any other sender do gets a response.